# JSP importar todos os arquivos de um diretório

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, importação

É possível **importar** todos os arquivos de um diretório com apenas uma chamada trabalhando com **JSP** ?

Hoje tenho o seguinte:

```
<script src="../resources/js/angular/directive/layout/mensagem.js"
    charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="../resources/js/angular/directive/layout/cabecalho-interno.js"
    charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Quero algo do gênero:

```
<script src="../resources/js/angular/directive/layout/*.js"
    charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: Não é possível (compativel com JSP)... você pode criar uma solução de contorno para atingir tal objetivo.

Comment: Poderia especificar qual seria essa solução @MarllonNasser ? Obrigado.

Comment: postei como "resposta", Mayllon... não sei se vai te atender :)

Answer (score 0):

Importar todos de uma vez eu nunca vi, mas se for muitos imports, você pode isolar eles em um arquivo e importar.

```
<%@ include file="imports.html" %>
<jsp:include page="imports.html" />
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @Matheus Silva, mas já tenho um arquivo onde irei importar todos os arquivos. Quero uma solução para não precisar importar arquivo por arquivo, também nunca vi isso com JSP's, mas já trabalhei assim em C#.

Answer (score 0):

Infelizmente isso ainda não é suportado pelo JSP..

Algumas soluções de contorno:

1- Sobrescrever o método `encodeEnd()` do `ScriptRenderer`.. (Isso é meio complicado....e depende também da versão do JSF..)

2- Colocar a lista de arquivos no `bean` e fazer um laço de repetição para percorrer tal propriedade e adicionar no `head`, algo como:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{seuBean.arquivos}" var="arq">
    <h:outputScript library="javascript" name="#{arq}" target="head" />
</ui:repeat>
```